# Drupal 7 Views - Node Content Not Appearing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have an issue in Drupal with getting node content to display itself. I suspect it could have to with the CSS styling, although I'm not 100% sure what's causing the issue.

**Background:**

So basically I'm trying to setup a blog but I'm running into serious issues trying to simply get the blog posts to display themselves.

I created a custom Drupal 7 theme using the export function of Artisteer (http://www.artisteer.com/?p=overview). A stylesheet called style.css was generated. I put some of my own CSS into this stylesheet along with the parts that were auto-generated. I should mention I did some amount of custom CSS to force the homepage to look the way I wanted.

I followed the instructions from the PDF at (http://learnbythedrop.com/buildingyourblog) to create a blog (great easy-to-follow guide). The most relevant pages for Views are pages 34 - 36, where he takes you through how to create a "Blog Post" view, in order to display your blog content correctly. However, when I got to the point where he created sample blog content and it displayed it's title and main content, this simply didn't work for me. See this link for example (Sample content that I created for testing purposes):

(http://www.productworld.com/blog-posts/2012/06/08/hello)

I can see a list of titles for sample content that I created (under the Recent Posts block), but I can't view any content from the individual blog posts themselves. The page is just blank.

Also, I can't see a list of the titles and teaser links - it should show up under (http://www.productworld.com/blog-posts) but that URL gives me a "page not found" error. This was something that worked in a previous iteration but now does not work.

Here are 2 screenshots of my View settings, in case it's relevant:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjK8u.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYbKa.png

**Questions:**

1. What is the likely cause of the blog content not displaying? (If I do a preview of the blog post within the Views section I can see the blog content just fine, it just won't display on the actual page.) Is it styling? Some setting in Views? Some Block setting? I've searched my style.css file and tried commenting out everything to do with "content:hidden" and "display:none" to no avail. I've tried every combination of settings in the blog posts View to no avail. I've tried placing "Main Page Content" and "View: Blog Posts" blocks in various regions, and changing around the settings that restrict where the block can be displayed. The blog post title/body content doesn't show up in the page source at all, which could be a clue. How would I go about debugging such a problem?
2. Why is www.productworld.com/blog-posts saying "page not found", even though I've specifically set up a view to create a page at this URL? And why does www.productworld.com/blog-posts/2012/06/14/hello-world-3 show up as a valid page, when it contains "blog-posts" in it's URL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I should display stuff to do with my stylesheet please let me know.

Comment: Make sure you break the lock that is shown in the first screenshot.  That could be interfering with the /blog-posts page.

Comment: @jsheffers, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately breaking the lock had no effect on the /blog-posts page. It does allow the saving of new changes to the view though.

Comment: Try clearing Drupal's cache, running update.php. Also try creating another view at /blog instead of /blog-posts and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: @jsheffers, clearing caches and running update.php did get the "blog-posts" URL working, so thanks for that! Here's what it looks like now: http://imgur.com/7uGy4 However, the main issue with the individual blog posts not displaying correctly still remains. When I click "Hello World 4" title from that screenshot, here's what I see: http://imgur.com/7aZR9 I've gotten to this point before and found it impossible to narrow the view down to show just the INDIVIDUAL node content, instead of everything it shows currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks as if you have panels overriding the Node template.  Which is why your node is not being displayed properly.

Go to Structure > Panels and see if the **Node Template** option under Manage pages is enabled.  If it is, that's probably your issue.  You can tell if it's enabled by looking to the right of the text to see whether it says enable or edit.

You can then edit that setting and then edit the content and choose Node > Body to get the body of the blog post to show correctly.

Take a look at this intro video to panels if you aren't familiar with it. http://yadadrop.com/drupal-video/panels-3-overview

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with the panels, I've a feeling that's the issue. Re: node template, see this pic: http://imgur.com/04H3Z - do I need to click edit on that setting, so that I can choose "Node Body"? (Or is Node Body someplace else?) Reason I ask is because I don't see "Node Body" once I click "Edit", here's what I see: http://imgur.com/0klry I'm on Drupal version 7.12 so perhaps the admin menus are laid out differently in the version I'm using? The video you linked had different menus for panels... Once again, thanks very much for all your help and patience.

Comment: Panels gives you great flexibility, but if you're a beginner it can be too much.  If you want the node to display normally just disable that panel. Follow some tutorials on panels to learn more about it, but this should get your node showing if you disable it.

Comment: the panels were indeed the cause of all the heartache. I'm using them for another part of the site to display stuff. I've a decision now - do I attempt to separate out panels so it continues to work for the old part of the site and doesn't affect the blog adversely? Or do I disable Node Template and re-style the old part, using Views for everything? Anyway, thanks a million for the help, wouldn't have thought of checking out Panels as the cause of the problem in a million years. Would bump up your karma except I'm below the threshold.

Comment: Hey patrick.  No problem!  If you edit the node template panel you can choose on the left column "Selection rules."  Choose node type and only select the content types you want panels to control.

Comment: that's a good suggestion, I'll have a look at all the options and see what is most straightforward. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take the leading '/' character out of your page path for the view - internal Drupal paths should generally never have that, but the system will prepend the configured base path to paths on your behalf (and it is probably already a '/').

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can't actually take out the leading slash, Drupal just displays it that way. Here is my "/blog-posts" URL setting: http://imgur.com/eXCbh

Comment: Gotchya - Different versions of views show the path on the overview screen differently, but you have it entered correctly.